# How do i change state of an array of objects in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a change to my state in react, and my state is

```
This.state = {
 Name: "alex",
 Referrals: [
   {
     Id: 1,
     HasRegistered: false,
     friend: {
      Name: "john",
      Age: "19",
      Amount: 150
    }
   },
   {
     Id: 2,
     HasRegistered: false,
     friend: {
      Name: "jane",
      Age: "18",
      Amount: 100
    }
   }
 ]
}
```

How can i change the properties of each object in the array of referrals

I tried using:

```
This.setState(prevState => {
  Return prevState.referrals.map(user => 
  {
    Return {
      ...user,
      HasRegistered: !user.HasRegistered,
      friend: {
       ...user.friend,
       Amount: user.friend.amount += 10
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Note: i used an onClick event to trigger the change in state, and considered the id of each user....
The code adds 10 to the amount but doesn't change the HasRegistered boolean to true 
Please what do i do?

Comment: Try adding parentheses around user.hasRegistered, so it becomes !(user.hasRegistered)

Comment: Did you mean to capitalize your `this` and `return` statements?

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript?

Comment: How on earth did you end up capitalizing all these words?

Comment: The capitalized letters were just typo errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea here, but perhaps the issue you're seeing is that you're returning a different state structure than before since `prevState` has a `referrals` property, but in your `setState` call, you're returning just the mapped referrals array. Also you have a `+= 10` which modifies the original object. Try this instead (I assume all those initial capital letters were mistakes):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  referrals: prevState.referrals.map(user => ({
    ...user,
    hasRegistered: !user.hasRegistered,
    friend: {
      ...user.friend,
      amount: user.friend.amount + 10
    }
  })
});
```